# Getting non-ASCII characters into WebBroker response in Delphi

Tags: delphi, utf-8, delphi-xe4, webbroker

I have a MS SQL Server database with nvarchar data, and in particular a data field with "★ABC★" in it. My Delphi desktop application displays it fine, but the same data from my  WebBroker application in Delphi XE4 that uses a TDataSetTableProducer to generate the response doesn't work. Here's the bare bones sample code:

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1TestAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Response.ContentEncoding := 'text/plain; charset="UTF-8"';
  Response.Content := '<!DOCTYPE html>'
  + '<html>'
  + '<body>'
  + '<p> ★ABC★ </p>'
  + '</body>'
  + '</html>'
end;
```

When viewed in a web browser, the result is "?ABC?". I've tried lots of things (including UTF-16 and prefixing the response with Char($FEFF)), but nothing helps. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'text/plain; charset="UTF-8"'` is not a valid value for the `Response.ContentEncoding` property.  You need to put it in the `Response.ContentType` property instead. Also, it should be using `text/html` instead of `text/plain`:

```
Response.ContentType := 'text/html; charset="UTF-8"';
```

If a browser is still not able to display the data correctly, you may have to use the `Response.ContentStream` property instead of the `Response.Content` property, so you can encode the UTF-8 data yourself:

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1TestAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Response.ContentType := 'text/html; charset="UTF-8"';
  Response.ContentStream := TStringStream.Create(
    '<!DOCTYPE html>'
    + '<html>'
    + '<body>'
    + '<p> ★ABC★ </p>'
    + '</body>'
    + '</html>',
    TEncoding.UTF8);
end;
```

Comment: Response.ContentType := 'text/html; charset="UTF-8"'; did the trick. Streaming was not necessary. Note that it is necessary to set the ContentType BEFORE setting the Content.

Comment: @Remy May I assume it should be `text/html` instead of `text/plain` as Kevin has it?

Comment: @BlurrySterk yes, it should. Don't know how I missed that before.